# How cancel from fire base authenticate disable account?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I accidentally pressed on the " disable account  " in the authenticate (phone number) in firebase site.
how I can cancel this "disable account" in the firebase site and not in the console

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to reenable the user account is by running a small program that uses the Admin SDK to change their `disabled` property back to `false`.

For example, in Node.js it'd be:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, { disabled: false })
```

For examples of how to do this on the other supported platforms see the documentation on [updating a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).